# Install phpmailer on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php

I dont know if this  [way to install phpmailer on ubuntu 16.04](https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/libphp-phpmailer) would work for php5.6

It would work with any php version?

Comment: May i ask what's the benefit of installing this way (system-wide i guess) from installing it from composer or using the [Minimal installation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#minimal-installation) in your specific project?

Comment: ¡Thanks! I installed from composer like you suggested me... it worked perfectly...